# Celery RabbitMQ CloudAMQP task queues not being consumed on Heroku

Tags: python, django, heroku, celery, cloudamqp

This example works on dev environment. On Heroku tasks get queued but are not consumed. Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

#### RabbitMQ Dashboard Shows:

`Name                            Parameters Policy  State   Ready Unacked Total
1f49ea51a56049f7a68082c6297ea080 Exp D AD   HA      idle    1     0       1     253eb525c95944d2b742f1f112cdc0e5 Exp D AD   HA      idle    1     0       1`

#### Proc File

```
web: gunicorn hellodjango.wsgi --workers 1
celery: python manage.py celery worker -E --time-limit=1200 --loglevel=ERROR
```

#### Setting.py

```
from os import environ
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "amqp"
BROKER_POOL_LIMIT = 0
BROKER_URL = environ.get('CLOUDAMQP_URL', '')
CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES = 14400
```

#### View

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from proj.tasks import add_to_count
from models import SampleCount
import logging
def test_async(request):
    sc = add_to_count.delay()
    count = SampleCount.objects.all()[0].num 
    return HttpResponse("test count: %s sc: %s name: %s " %(count,sc,add_to_count.name ))
```

#### Model

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
class SampleCount(models.Model):
    num = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

#### Tasks.py

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from celery import shared_task
from proj.models import SampleCount
from celery import task
@task(name='proj.tasks')
def add_to_count():
    try:
        sc = SampleCount.objects.get(pk=1)
    except:
        sc = SampleCount()
    sc.num = sc.num + 2
    sc.save()
    return(sc)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem and in my case I think it something about naming.  In your procfile you were using manage.py whereas [heroku recommend](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/celery-heroku#creating-a-celery-app) something like:

```
worker: celery worker --app=tasks.app
```

Answer (score 0):

limit the concurrency of your celery worker, `-c 1`

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I tried -c 1 and -c=1 --c 1 none worked.